# how to concatinate a link with <select> <option> value on "onchange" event

Tags: php, magento

`<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>` gives me my index page url .i.e. www.domain.com/index.php/

But now, what I want is, when any particular option is selected, it should add to this url.
.e.g.

```
www.domain.com/index.php/wordpress/
```

I write this code for it but now don know how to get it done. :(

```
<select onchange="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>')">
     <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
     <option value="wordpress">Wordpress</option>
     <option value="drupal">drupal</option>
     <option value="magento">Megento</option>
</select>
```

Also, I had searched this link but couldn't take help from it. As it didnt work for me.

```
<select name="forma" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
 <option value="Home">Home</option>
 <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
 <option value="Sitemap">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think u miss something, your question is incomplete

Comment: You can format source code via the `{}` button in the rich text editor.

Comment: Do you want to redirect `www.domain.com/index.php/wordpress/
` here when `wordpress` get selected?

Comment: actually this magento and wordpress etc option are categories to which i want to direct my link on change event of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this (note that I've added `this` as the first argument):

```
<select onchange="setLocation(this, '<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>')">
     <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
     <option value="wordpress">Wordpress</option>
     <option value="drupal">drupal</option>
     <option value="magento">Megento</option>
</select>
```

You could write the following JS:

```
function setLocation(elm, baseUrl) {
    var keyword = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value; // Gets the selected keyword (some sanity check could be done)
    window.location = 'http://' + baseUrl + keyword + '/'; // Redirects
}
```

---

Alternatively:

```
<select name="forma" onchange="window.location='http://<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + '/';">
 <option value="Home">Home</option>
 <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
 <option value="Sitemap">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

(**EDIT** Prepended `http://` to both examples.)

Comment: @atif [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/FDf4T/). Could you please post the `<select>` tag as it's output from PHP?

Comment: @atif Oh, I edited. Just noticed that the `getUrl()` method does not start with `http://`. I've added this to both examples.

Comment: there was a js conflict :) i removed my js included and it worked without http:// :)